# Exchange 2010 SP1 Web Services create contact issue

Tags: exchange-2010, contacts, exchange

We just had a custom app developed that pulls contact data from our CRM database and uses Exchange Web Services to create contacts in Exchange users contacts folder.  The app is working great except all contacts that are also in the Exchange organization are getting their contact type created as 'EX' by EWS instead of 'SMTP'.

For example, the Exchange server is hosting addresses for the domain @abcd.com, any contact created that has a email address ending in @abcd.com is created with Email Address Type of EX.

This is causing a big issue as BES will not sync contacts with email address type set to EX to Blackberrys, it only syncs SMTP type.

Manually creating a contact in Outlook with the @abcd.com domain results in the email address type of SMTP.

**Question: Is there a way through EWS to change the email address type to SMTP?  Or is there a setting in Exchange 2010 that is somehow causing the type to be set to EX?**

Since this is using EWS I know it might be better asked over on Stackoverflow but I was hoping the many Exchange Admins on SF one might be able to help me out.